# CSS for full-width button for Modal Pop-up

Tags: css, wordpress

I want to make the green button at the bottom of the `nav` area on [this page](https://compucademy.co.uk/stg_2b77a/?page_id=117) full width (across the whole page, with the text centered).

I've tried adding `width:100%` to 3 of the `divs` which I though were relevant, but no joy. I've also tried quite a few other tricks. I can only use `css` as the whole modal poop-up is handled by a WordPress plugin which I don't want to tamper with.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Your banner is a flex.... and it has bootstrap styles that specify it should be only 2 colomns big out of 12..... So you migth first wanna look into the bootstrap part. Also consider that your nav is wrapped in an 8 collomn style... (col-md-8 for dekstop) so your 100% doesnt go up here. Not to mention the container where that all is wrapped in .. tadaa. So you have 3 wrapped elements right there before you reach even your button.

Comment: In theory you dont have to mess with the code... Not sure how it's build up, but you have to manage this in the page editor, instead of asking for a css solution

Comment: I have edited my page template by adding `echo `do_shortcode...` in the `nav` area.

Answer (score 2):

Try to move your element `<div class="banner-button">` out of the current hierarchy and place after element `<div class="col-md-8 desktop-only"` in side element `<div class="row"`>

since it is inside `nav` nothing works with `width` 
if you want to work with same hierarchy please use `css : position` properties

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like that

[image]

If yes then you have to made some changes into your html like

```
<nav >
<ul>
<div class="banner-button">
<div class="md-trigger md-setperspective btn-bg-2160 btn btn-lg text-center">

Css must be 

.md-trigger.md-setperspective.btn-bg-2160.btn.btn-lg.text-center {
    width: 100%;
}
.banner-button {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 91;
    text-align: center;
    top: 72px;
}
```

Best way to do this take out your button from `<div class="col-md-8 desktop-only">` then add `<div class="col-md-12">` and wrap your button inside this.